# how can i play an audio file in background using "App registers for location updates" background mode

Tags: ios, audio, background, location

I am using "App registers for location updates" background mode in my application to get the location information from background.My requirement is that, i need to play an audio file,if user closer(around 100 meters) to a predefined location. this is working fine when the app is active(foreground) but it is not playing any audio from background.

```
  self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init ];
  self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
  self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  self.locationManager.delegate = self;
 [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


 // delegate method
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:definedLocation];
 //Check the distance between the newLocation and userDefinedLOcation
if (distance <=100.00) {
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"alarmSound"]]];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
player.numberOfLoops = -1;
player.currentTime = 0;
player.volume =1;
player.delegate=self;
[player prepareToPlay];
  [player play];

}
}
```

how can i play the audio file in background using "App registers for location updates" background mode, help me to achieve this.  my app get rejected as I used "app plays audio" background mode before. So i don't want to use audio background mode.
Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explicitly set the Audio Session category?

The Audio Session Programming Guide has a useful section "Choosing the Best Category" which describes the different options: 
[Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW3)

I'm not in front of a Mac right now, so I can't test this. But I suspect adding the following to your viewDidLoad method might help you out when you multitask away from your app.

```
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
```

Comment: yes, i had already added AVAudioSession. [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

Comment: `UIBackgroundModes` is an array. You mention you have added "App registers for location updates". Have you also added the audio value to the `UIBackgroundModes` array? I think the description in Xcode is "App plays audio".

Comment: as i am not playing audio continuously in the background(playing audio at certain point only), i am not supposed to add "app plays audio" background mode in plist.if it happens then apple will reject the app.

Comment: I can't confirm that Apple will reject the app or not, but reading through the documentation I haven't seen any requirements about continuously playing audio. This user seems to have had an issue with an app rejection however it seems you can dispute the decision to some success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980481/my-app-has-been-rejected-because-of-uibackgroundmodes