# adding UIBackgroundModes "audio" gets app rejected when playing a video for AirPlay?

Tags: ios, airplay

I am developing an app that streams HLS videos on AVPlayer. As per the guide over here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html 
and here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010209-CH1-VIDEO
inside the Important box.

With respect to this  [My App has been rejected because of UIBackgroundModes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980481/my-app-has-been-rejected-because-of-uibackgroundmodes) ,

they reject the app if done so -- if I don't add the key, the AirPlay quits as soon as I navigate out of the app by pressing home button, is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote them this line from there own documentation

**Important:** The *UIBackgroundModes* audio key will also allow apps to stream media content in the background using AirPlay

Taken from documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html://) . I exactly had the same issue and quoted them this documentation and then the app was accepted.